# How to get basic info of near wallet from near api?

Tags: near, near-api-js, near-wallet

I am trying to get the basic info shown in the near wallet using near API.
I want to fetch the info regarding stake and staking reward, basically all the info like:-
[image]

I am able to get the stacked near amount but not getting `Reward earned`, `Pending release`, and `Available for withdrawal`

I tried these APIs

https://docs.near.org/api/rpc/contracts

https://docs.near.org/tools/near-api-js/contract

```
async function getAccountBalance(accountId) {
    const near = await connect(config);
    const protocolConfig = await near.connection.provider.experimental_protocolConfig({ finality: 'final' });
    let state = await near.connection.provider.query({
        request_type: 'view_account',
        account_id: accountId,
        finality: 'optimistic'
    });
    const costPerByte = new bn_js_1.default(protocolConfig.runtime_config.storage_amount_per_byte);
     console.log(formatNearAmount(costPerByte));
     
    const stateStaked = new bn_js_1.default(state.storage_usage).mul(costPerByte);
    console.log(formatNearAmount(stateStaked));
    const staked = new bn_js_1.default(state.locked);
    console.log(formatNearAmount(staked));
    const totalBalance =await new bn_js_1.default(state.amount).add(staked);
    console.log(formatNearAmount(totalBalance));
    const availableBalance = totalBalance.sub(bn_js_1.default.max(staked, stateStaked));
    console.log(formatNearAmount(availableBalance));

    console.log("Storage cost - total balance ---? ", formatNearAmount(availableBalance));
}
```